# Is it always possible to convert a class that implements the content manager into function that uses contextmanager decorator?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have the following class that implements the context manager protocol:

```
class Indenter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.level += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.level -= 1

    def print(self, text):
        print('\t' * self.level + text)
```

The following code:

```
with Indenter() as indent:
    indent.print('bye!')
    with indent:
        indent.print('goodbye')
        with indent:
            indent.print('au revoir')
    indent.print('bye bye')
```

produces the following output:

```
    bye!
        goodbye
            au revoir
    bye bye
```

Now, I want to produce the same functionality, but instead of implementing a class, I want to use the `contextmanager` decorator. I have the following code so far:

```
class Indenter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0

    def print(self, text):
        print('\t' * self.level + text)


@contextmanager
def indenter():
    try:
        i = Indenter()
        i.level += 1
        yield i
    finally:
        i.level -= 1
```

However, I cannot produce the same output when I call:

```
with indenter() as indent:
    indent.print('hi!')
    with indent:
        indent.print('hello')
        with indent:
            indent.print('bonjour')
    indent.print('hey')
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve what I am doing with the class that implements the context manager with the function decorated by the `contextmanager` decorator?

**Main question:**

Is it possible to convert any class that implements the context manager protocol into a function that uses the `contextmanager` decorator? What are the limitations of each option? Are there cases in which one is better than the other?

Comment: Why, though? You already have working code, and now you want to wrap this into a function wrapped into `contextmanager`, while you already have a class implementing the context manager protocol...

Comment: @ForceBru, it is just for the sake of experimenting. Honestly I don't have practical reason, just curiosity if that is possible to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do, at least not directly.

Your `Indenter.__enter__` returns an `Indenter` object. Then, your nested `with indent:` uses that `Indenter` object as a context manager—which is fine, because it is one.

Your `indenter` function yields an `Indenter` object. Then, your nested `with indent:` uses that `Indenter` object as a context manager—which fails, because it isn't one.

---

You'd need to change things so that what you return is not an `Indenter` object, but another call to `indenter`. While this is possible (any class can be rewritten as a closure), it's probably not what you want here.

If you're willing to change the API slightly, you can do this:

```
@contextmanager
def indenter():
    level=0
    @contextmanager
    def _indenter():
        nonlocal level
        try:
            level += 1
            yield
        finally:
            level -= 1
    def _print(text):
        print('\t' * level + text)
    _indenter.print = _print
    yield _indenter
```

Now, `indenter` doesn't create a context manager, but it does create a function that returns a context manager. That's inherent in what the `@contextmanager` decorator does—just as you have to do `with indenter() as indent:`, not `with indenter as indent:`, you'll have to do `with indent():`, not `with indent`.

Otherwise, it's all pretty straightforward. Instead of using recursion, I just created a new function that stores `level` in a closure. And then we can `contextmanager` it and tack the `print` method on. And now:

```
>>> with indenter() as indent:
...     indent.print('hi!')
...     with indent():
...         indent.print('hello')
...         with indent():
...             indent.print('bonjour')
...     indent.print('hey')
hi!
    hello
        bonjour
hey
```

---

If you're wondering why we can't just `yield _indenter()` (well, we'd have to call `_indenter()`, then tack the `print` onto the result, then `yield` that, but that's not the main issue), the problem is that `contextmanager` demands a generator function that yields once, and gives you a single-use context manager every time you call it. If you read the [`contextlib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/contextlib.py) source, you can see how you could write something like `contextmanager` that instead takes a function that yields alternating enters and exits forever and gives you a context manager that does a `next` for each `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Or you could write a class that that creates the generator on `__enter__` instead of on `__init__` so it can do the `_recreate_cm` thing properly the same way it does when used as a decorator instead of a context manager. But at that point, to avoid writing a class, you're writing two classes and a decorator, which seems a bit silly.

---

If you're interested in more, you should check out [`contextlib2`](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/), a third-party module written by Nick Coghlan and the other authors of the stdlib `contextlib`. It's used both for backporting `contextlib` features to older versions of Python, and for experimenting with new features for future versions of Python. IIRC, at one point, they had a version of `@contextmanager` that was reusable, but removed it because of a bug that couldn't be worked around cleanly.

Comment: @abarnet, I was thinking to implement something as a recursive function that uses this decorator, but the problem is that I don't really know the base case that allows me to terminate the recursion. What is the not direct way in which I can achieve this? My major question is: Is it possible to convert any class that implements the context manager protocol into a function that uses the `contextmanager` decorator?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf A recursive generator function only solves half the problem; you also have to attach `print` as an attribute to whatever thing you return. Are you willing to change your nested statements from `with indent:` to `with indent():`? I'm pretty sure it'll be less bad if you are. Either way, if you've answered by the time I get back to my computer, I'll slap something together and edit the answer.

Comment: I appreciate a lot the extra information you have provided. I will definitely check it. Thanks again.